# Attached Property. How to use SetValue in PropertyChangedCallback

Tags: c#, wpf, attached-properties

I need Attached Property that sets focus to UIElement from ViewModel.
I've created Attached property and in PropertyChangedCallback I set focus to UIElement.

```cs
private static void VoySetFocusChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (o is UIElement)
  {
    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {
      (o as UIElement).Focus();
      (o as UIElement).SetValue(VoySetFocusProperty, false);
    }
  }
}
```

but I want it to work like trigger in shotgun. I set true to Test in ViewModel ...
   it invokes PropertyChangedCallback in MyAttachedProperties class,sets focus to UIElement

```cs
((o as UIElement).Focus();
```

and value of Test in ViewModel returns to false

```
((o as UIElement).SetValue(VoySetFocusProperty, false);)
```

Everything seems to work fine but SetValue doesn't change my value in ViewModel back.

Full code:

View:

```cs
<Window x:Class="WpfAttachedProperty.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAttachedProperty"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="127" Width="316">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox local:MyAttachedProperties.VoySetFocus="{Binding Path=Test,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" Text="Focus Me"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Click to Focus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfAttachedProperty
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow:Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Command Class
/// </summary>
public class DelegateCommand:ICommand
{
  private readonly Action _action;

  public DelegateCommand(Action action)
  {
    _action = action;
  }

  public void Execute(object parameter)
  {
    _action();
  }

  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
    return true;
  }

  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add
    {
    }
    remove
    {
    }
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// ViewModelClass
/// </summary>
public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private bool _test = false;
  public bool Test
  {
    get
    {
      return _test;
    }
    set
    {
      _test = value;
      this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Test");
    }
  }
  public ICommand MyCommand
  {
    get
    {
      return new DelegateCommand(SetTestToTrue);
    }
  }
  private void SetTestToTrue()
  {
    this.Test = true;
  }

  #region INotifyPropertyChanged
  public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String PropertyName)
  {
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
      this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
  }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  #endregion
}


public class MyAttachedProperties
{
  public static Object GetVoySetFocus(DependencyObject obj)
  {
    return (Object)obj.GetValue(VoySetFocusProperty);
  }

public static void SetVoySetFocus(DependencyObject obj, Object value)
{
  obj.SetValue(VoySetFocusProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty VoySetFocusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VoySetFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(MyAttachedProperties), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(VoySetFocusChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceVoySetFocus)));

private static object CoerceVoySetFocus(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
  return (bool)baseValue;
}

private static void VoySetFocusChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (o is UIElement)
  {
    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {
      (o as UIElement).Focus();
      // Doesn't set Test to false in ViewModel
      (o as UIElement).SetValue(VoySetFocusProperty, false);
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Greetings Marko.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue is with the line:

```
((o as UIElement).SetValue(VoySetFocusProperty, false);)
```

You should instead use **[SetCurrentValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx)** to set the DP.

```
((o as UIElement).SetCurrentValue(VoySetFocusProperty, false);)
```

**Explanation**:

Setting the value directly of any DependencyProperty breaks the binding it with source property.

However, `SetCurrentValue` doesn't break the binding and push back the value back to the source property. Explanation from MSDN for SetCurrentValue:

> This method is used by a component that programmatically sets the
>   value of one of its own properties without disabling an application's
>   declared use of the property. The SetCurrentValue method **changes the
>   effective value of the property, but existing triggers, data bindings,
>   and styles will continue to work**.

---

Moreover, I think setting it in `PropertyChanged` callback won't propagate that back to Viewmodel if do the operation synchronously since it reaches to callback from Viewmodel property setter only.

So, what we can do is **do this operation asynchronously** by enqueuing it on dispatcher using `BeginInvoke` so that it gets propagate to viewmodel Test property.

```
(o as UIElement).Focus();
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
{
    // Doesn't set Test to false in ViewModel
    (o as UIElement).SetCurrentValue(VoySetFocusProperty, false);
});
```

Comment: But I also want to set Test in ViewModel to false
It is not set after
(o as UIElement).SetCurrentValue(VoySetFocusProperty, false);

Comment: Since the mode is twoWay for binding. It will automatically push the value to source.

Comment: I think I dont't understand Your answer. What should be changed to make it work the way I want it to work?
SetCurrentValue invoked from codeBehind changes Test in ViewModel. It doesn't work in PropertyChangedCallback

Comment: @tomatino - I have updated my answer. Please check and in case that solves your query, do accept it. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Rohit Vat's suggestion worked for me. What seems to be occurring is that the binding is not updated until after the Property Changed Callback. This meant (for me anyway), that the source of the binding (in my View Model) was not updated if I called SetCurrentValue synchronously within the Property Changed Callback.

Calling SetCurrentValue asynchronously as suggested solved this issue for me.

```
(o as UIElement).Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    (o as UIElement).SetCurrentValue(VoySetFocusProperty, false);
}));
```